# Multiple Imputation procedure for each outcome or all outcomes

Tags: multiple-imputation

What is the correct way to perform multiple imputation of covariates with regards to multiple outcomes, say 3? Is it better to impute covariates for each outcome (3 imputation models) or should I create a single imputation model with all the outcomes in that model? All outcomes are of the same type.

Thank you!